# Extract First Name Middle Name and Last Name Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I Have come close to finding the solution but not completely.  I want to separate the first, middle (if it exists) and last names in separate name field. The data & current results:

```
Data             FName           LName
Doe,John         John            Doe
Doe,John A       John A          Doe
Doe,John Art, Jr John Art, Jr    Doe
```

The Code:

```
First_Name: Mid([Client Name],InStr([Client Name],",")+1)
Last_Name: Left([Client Name],InStr([Client Name],",")-1)
```

As you can see, I am not focused on the middle name right now, but would like to capture that as well in a MName for the middle name/initial.  I have found many options on the web getting close to this but none which accomplishes the task of having the data look like:

```
Data             FName         MName      LName
Doe,John         John                     Doe
Doe,John A       John          A          Doe
Doe,John Art, Jr John          Art        Doe Jr
Doe,John A, Jr   John          A          Doe JR
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**edited**: added `mName` initalization

try this

Option Explicit

```
Sub names()

Dim namesRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant
Dim fName As String, mName As String, lName As String

Set namesRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10") '<== here set the actual range of "Data", header excluded

For Each cell In namesRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

    arr = Split(cell.value, ",")
    lName = Trim(arr(0))
    If UBound(arr) = 2 Then lName = lName & " " & Trim(arr(2))
    arr = Split(Trim(arr(1)))
    fName = Trim(arr(0))
    mName=""
    If UBound(arr) = 1 Then mName = Trim(arr(1))

    cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3) = Array(fName, mName, lName)

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked very well for me - thank you!  I added a "currentRow = cell.Row" variable so that I could plug the parsed names into a separate column as Range("AA" & currentRow).Value = fname, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace commas with spaces and replace resulting double spaces with single spaces.

Then start splitting the string out based on spaces.

Assumptions:

There will ALWAYS be at least a first and last name, an IF like the ones in my code will get around this if there is potential for just a first name.

There will only ever be ONE suffix to a surname (ie jr)

```
Sub FixNames()
Dim MyString As String, FirstName As String, MiddlePart As String, Surname As String, X As Long
For X = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    FirstName = "": MiddlePart = "": Surname = ""
    MyString = Replace(Replace(Range("A" & X).text, ",", " "), "  ", " ")
    FirstName = Split(Replace(MyString, ",", " "), " ")(1)
    Surname = Split(Replace(MyString, ",", " "), " ")(0)
    If Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, " ", "")) >= 2 Then MiddlePart = Split(Replace(MyString, ",", " "), " ")(2)
    If Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, " ", "")) > 2 Then Surname = Surname & " " & Split(Replace(MyString, ",", " "), " ")(3)
    Range("B" & X).Formula = FirstName
    Range("C" & X).Formula = MiddlePart
    Range("D" & X).Formula = Surname
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Option Explicit

Sub names()

```
Dim name As String

Dim first_name As String
Dim mid_name As String
Dim last_name As String

name = "AA,BB,CC"

first_name = Left(name, InStr(name, ",") - 1)

mid_name = Mid(name, InStr(name, ",") + 1, InStrRev(name, ",") - InStr(name, ",") - 1)

last_name = Right(name, Len(name) - InStrRev(name, ","))

MsgBox first_name & Chr(10) & mid_name & Chr(10) & last_name
```

End Sub